# Softlayer ReST API to get billing Items for a user

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I want to retrieve billing items on next invoice for a particular user I am using

```
GET: https://{{sluser}}:{{slkey}}@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getNextInvoiceTopLevelBillingItems?mask[id,orderItem[id,order[userRecordId,userRecord[my_user_name]]],invoiceItem[id,totalRecurringAmount]]
```

where my_user_name is my softlayer user name but this mask does not give me the records corresponding to my_user_name. Anything wrong with the mask?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply filters by “username”, for example:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getNextInvoiceTopLevelBillingItems?objectFilter={   "nextInvoiceTopLevelBillingItems": {      "orderItem": {       "order": {         "userRecord": {           "username": {             "operation": "myUsername"           }         }       }     }   } }&objectMask=mask[id,orderItem[order[userRecord]]]

Method: GET
```